# Can you please check my proof of identification topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I tried to prove the following:

If $C$ is a cylinder with boundary circles $S_1$ and $S_2$ then the space resulting from identifying $S_1$ and $S_2$ by mapping them homeomorphically onto a circle $S$ is a torus.

Can you please read my proof and check if it is correct? here is my proof:

Let $T = S^1 \times S^1$ denote the torus and $C = S^1 \times [0,1] $ the cylinder. Assume a homeomorphism $h: [0,1]/\sim \to S^1$ is given. Let's use $C \cup_f S$ to denote the space obtained from $C$ and $S=S^1$ by identifying the boundary $S_1 \cup S_2$ of $C$ where $f: S_1 \cup S_2 \to S$ is defined as $f((s_1,1)) = s_1$ and $f((s_2,2)) = s_2$ where $s_1 \in S_1 = S^1 \times \{1\}, s_2 \in S_2 = S^1 \times \{2\}$.

Note that $C \cup_f S$ is a space consisting of points $S^1 \times (0,1)  \cup S^1 \times \{0\}$. Define a map $\varphi : C \cup_f S \to S^1 \times S^1$ as $(s,t) \mapsto (s, h(t))$. Then $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Depending on how you identity the two circles. Indeed you might as well get the Klein bottle.

Comment: @John Thanks I added a definition of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

The space $C\cup_f S$ is a quotient of the disjoint union $C\sqcup S$ obtained by identifying $s\in S_1\sqcup S_2$ with $f(s)\in S$. In order to obtain a map from $C∪_f S$ to $S^1\times S^1$, you first need a map from that disjoint union to the torus. You can take
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
(s,h(t)), &\text{ if }x=(s,t)\in C\\
(s,0),    &\text{ if }x=s\in S
\end{cases}$$
As this map sends points to the same image if and only if these points are identified via $f$, it induces a bijection $\tilde g:C∪_fS\to S^1×S^1$. So you were on the right track. You just need an argument on why this continuous bijection is a homeomorphism.

Comment: How does one prove that $g$ is a homeomorphism?